# TypeError: Cannot read property 'destroy' of null При попытке закрыть balloon

Tags: yandex-maps-api

При создании `balloonContentLayout` с помощью `templateLayoutFactory`:

```
ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass(`
<div>
    BALLOON
</div>
`,
  {
      build: () => {
          BalloonContentLayout.superclass.build.call(this);
      },
      clear: () => {
          BalloonContentLayout.superclass.clear.call(this);
      }
  });
```

Балун позиционируется в левом верхнем углу с пустым контентом, и при попытке закрыть вываливается `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'destroy' of null`

Но если не передавать второй аргумент, то все работает правильно. В чем ошибка?

[Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/0bLp15va/24/) на jsfiddle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Дело в контексте. Стрелочные функции при создании сохраняют свой контекст, а у обычных он плавает в зависимости от того как их вызывают. Сделайте так:

```
build: function(){ 
    BalloonContentLayout.superclass.build.call(this);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/10ak5dhc/